# No access to admin page after change my server and domain

Tags: debugging

I have changed my website to a new domain and server. I can navigate throught my content. However, after login I can't access to admin pages. No error is shown, only blank page.

What I did was upload a new `.htaccess`, delete the cache tables, uncomment on `settings.php` the line "Base URL (optional)". $base_url (replacing example.com with my site).

I don't know what can I do. Any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems and there are the several steps that you should do for solving your problems:

**1**.Add the Error reporting debug ability in settings.php by adding these lines:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

These lines should be comment out after debug or after solving problems.

**2**.Browse the website and see what error information that you will get. If there is error with timeout or memory problem. Please change the memory_limit or max_execution_time if your hosting support to do that.

**3**.If there are some problems with the PHP version(There are some differences between PHP 4 and PHP 5). You will consider to upgrade or not.

**4**. Sometime there are several issues that are related to database or .htaccess. You'll see on the debug information and try to fix one by one

Answer (score 0):

You might need to increase memory_limit in php.ini . Check if php memory of new server is same as old server.